# Append text to URL in Fiddler/Javascript

Tags: javascript, fiddler

What I want to do with Fiddler is set up a custom rule to have it check the URL of an outgoing request and if it contains a certain text string, to add an extra portion of text to the end of the URL.

I've updated my code on the advice from a comment below and I guess it checks out as I'm not getting an error message any more. My new code is as follows:

```
static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) {

    var newtext = "text to append to url";

    if (oSession.url.Contains("text to search for")){
       oSession.url.concat(newtext);
    }

}
```

Unfortunately the extra text is still not being added to the end of the URL before the request gets sent out to the server. Any further help would be greatly appreciated (please be kind, I'm still new to Fiddler and Javascript)!

Many thanks.

**SOLVED!**
Thanks to EricLaw at the official Fiddler user groups I now have a solution:

```
static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) {

    if (oSession.uriContains("targetString")) {
          var sText = "Enter a string to append to a URL";
          oSession.fullUrl = oSession.fullUrl + sText;
    }
}
```

Comment: url is of string type. use Concate method instead of Add

Comment: i am not sure but try using oSession.url=oSession.url.concat(newtext); i havnt worked with fiddler

Comment: I've got a solution, but thanks again for your help!